# EXC_BAD_ACCESS about vector in struct vector in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, vector

I tried making a data structure in C++ by STL vector, however, I got a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at `// error here` after running the program below (on Xcode). Is there any solution?

The data structure `nodes` is a vector, one of which member is also a vector `costs`.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct t_node{
    int id;
    vector<int> costs;
};


int main(){
    vector<t_node> nodes;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        t_node input_node;

        input_node.id = i;
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            input_node.costs.push_back(j);
        }

        nodes.push_back(move(input_node));  // error here, "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It could be because of `input_node` is temporal...?

(Thanks for the comments, I updated the code)

Comment: please provide a [mre], your code doesn't compile

Comment: I get two compilation errors; "No template named 'vector'", and "'main' must return 'int'". Please post real code.

Comment: You are using `emplace_back()` incorrectly, it is for inplace construction of elements i.e. the method accepts the _arguments_ for the element's constructor.  You should be using the move `push_back()` overload: `nodes.push_back(std::move(input_node))`.

Comment: Use push_back instead of emplace_back

Comment: Can't reproduce. I can see two reasons for this crash: either your XCode installation is severely broken, or that's not your actual code.

Comment: `nodes.emplace_back(std::move(input_node))` is fine.  This will call the move constructor for `t_node`, and in my tests results in slightly better optimized code.